# IMAP: not a valid imap resource

Tags: php, imap

I am experiencing problems with IMAP resources in PHP: I the error `supplied is not a valid imap resource` for the following code:

```
$imap = imap_open("{"."$host:$port/imap$ssl"."}$folder", $user, $pass);
imap_headers($imap);
$new_emails = imap_search($imap, "UNSEEN");
imap_close($imap);
$counter = $counter+count($new_emails);
```

I get the following errors:

```
warning: imap_close(): supplied is not a valid imap resource on line 896.
warning: imap_headers(): supplied is not a valid imap resource on line 892.
warning: imap_search(): supplied is not a valid imap resource on line 894.
```

**Edit**

I'm now also getting:

```
NO IMAP CONNECTION Notice: Undefined variable: imap_connection in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 214
Warning: imap_getmailboxes(): supplied argument is not a valid imap resource in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 216
Notice: Undefined variable: imap_connection in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 220
Warning: imap_headers(): supplied argument is not a valid imap resource in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 220
Notice: Undefined variable: imap_connection in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 222 
Connection failed! Notice: Undefined property: model::$no_mail in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/view/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 1346
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/view/helpdesk_finance_admin.php on line 1403
```

Comment: Warning: imap_open() [0function.imap-open0]: Couldn't open stream {webmail.talent.co.uk:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/the_helpdesk.php on line 892 Warning: imap_headers(): supplied argument is not a valid imap resource in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/the_helpdesk.php on line 894 Warning: imap_search(): supplied argument is not a valid imap resource in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/the_helpdesk.php on line 896

Comment: Warning: imap_close(): supplied argument is not a valid imap resource in /var/www/vhosts/talent.co.uk/httpdocs/intranet/model/the_helpdesk.php on line 898

Comment: You should give the context (code) of the new error. How could we know what you did? Did you check if $imap is not FALSE?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an error and `imap_open` returns `FALSE` which is not a valid resource to be passed to `imap_close`.

Always check the results of operations that can fail

Answer (score 0):

The Login details were wrong, so imap couldn't connect succcesfully and that therefore lead to an error code.

Answer (score 0):

try with this syntaxe 
{webmail.talent.co.uk:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX